# Python: How to pass key to a dictionary from the variable of a function?

Tags: python, function, dictionary

Basically I have two dictionaries: one is a `Counter()` the other is `dict()`

The first one contains all the unique words in a text, as keys and each words' frequency in the text, as the values

The second contains the same unique words as keys, but the values are the definitions which are user-inputted.

The latter is what I'm having trouble implementing. I created a function which takes in a word, checks if that word is in the frequency dictionary, and if it is, allows the user to input a definition of that word (else, it will print an error). The word and its definition are then added to the second dictionary as a key-value pair (using `dict.update(word=definition)`).

But whenever I run the program I get the error:

Nameerror: name '' is not defined

Here is the code:

```
import string
import collections
import pickle

freq_dict = collections.Counter()
dfn_dict = dict()

def cleanedup(fh):
    for line in fh:
        word = ''
        for character in line:
            if character in string.ascii_letters:
                word += character
            else:
                yield word
                word = ''

def process_book(textname):
    with open (textname) as doc:
        freq_dict.update(cleanedup(doc))
    global span_freq_dict
    span_freq_dict = pickle.dumps(freq_dict)


def show_Nth_word(N):
    global span_freq_dict
    l = pickle.loads(span_freq_dict)
    return l.most_common()[N]

def show_N_freq_words(N):    
    global span_freq_dict
    l = pickle.loads(span_freq_dict)
    return l.most_common(N)

def define_word(word):
    if word in freq_dict:
        definition = eval(input('Please define ' + str(word) + ':'))
        dfn_dict({word: definition})
    else:
        return print('Word not in dictionary!')



process_book('DQ.txt')
process_book('HV.txt')

# This was to see if the if/else was working
define_word('asdfs')
#This is the actual word I want to add
define_word('de')

print(dfn_dict.items())
```

I get the feeling that either the error is very small or very big. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: So the program now allows me to enter a definition, but returns this error once I do so:

```
>>> 
Word not in dictionary!
Please define esperar:To await
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User 3.1\Desktop\Code Projects\dict.py", line 50, in <module>
    define_word('esperar')
  File "C:\Users\User 3.1\Desktop\Code Projects\dict.py", line 37, in define_word
    definition = eval(input('Please define ' + str(word) + ':'))
  File "<string>", line 1
    To await
           ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
>>>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dict.update(word=definition)` won’t do what you think it does. See this example:

```
>>> someDict = {}
>>> word = 'foo'
>>> definition = 'bar'
>>> someDict.update(word=definition)
>>> someDict
{'word': 'bar'}
```

As you can see, this method will always update the key `word` although you want the `word` variable to be resolved first. This won’t work though because you are passing a named argument to the `update` function, and those named arguments are taken literally.

If you want to update the key that equals to the value of `word`, you can just do it like this:

```
someDict[word] = definition
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, upon updating the code to use this method I get either a Syntax error (on the "=" symbol). Or (if I delete "return" and just leave it as dfn_dict[word]=definition) a Nameerror again (same as before)

Comment: Yes, you can’t do `return dfn_dict[word] = definition`. You would have to split that into two lines, e.g. `dfn_dict[word] = definition` and then `return dfn_dict`. But since you are modifying the global `dfn_dict` anyway (btw. no need to call global here), you don’t actually need to return it.

Comment: @ShihabDider `eval(input('Please define ' + str(word) + ':'))` You definitely want to drop the `eval` there.

Comment: Having done this, I now get `dfn_dict({word: definition})
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

Comment: @ShihabDider Please read the answer again? You are trying something completely different now.

Comment: Thanks so much! You were totally right, I changed the key update part, back to your suggestion and it now works perfectly. I just realized I forgot the `.update` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

`dfn_dict.update(word = definition)` is equivalent to `dfn_dict.update({"word": definition})`. You want to use `dfn_dict.update({word: definition})`.

Answer (score 0):

input() actually evaluates the input as Python code. Use `raw_input` instead.

```
def define_word(word):                    
    if word in freq_dict:
        definition = raw_input('Please define ' + str(word) + ':')
        global dfn_dict
        return dfn_dict.update({word: definition})
    else:
        print('Word not in dictionary!')

process_book('DQ.txt')

# This was to see if the if/else was working
define_word('asdfs')
#This is the actual word I want to add
define_word('esperar')

print(dfn_dict.items())
```

Comment: Nope, still getting the same NameError

Comment: @ShihabDider i execute this code and it works, are you sure you replaced input to raw_input? or also to eval(input(..))?

Comment: I was mistaken earlier, its not the same NameError, it now says: Name 'raw_input' is not defined. Also I've edited the OP with updated code

Comment: EDIT: I tried using eval(input()) the NameError is gone, but now in its place is: SyntaxError unxpected EOF while parsing (see OP for full details)

Comment: @ShihabDider which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.4.1